# Is a uniform distribution inside a rectangle remains the same inside a circle?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If a set of points are uniformly distributed inside a rectangle, is the distribution of the points remain the same inside a circle that is also inside a rectangle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a classical application of the rejection sampling algorithm:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling#Examples

More formally, a r.v. $X$ with uniform distribution on a rectangle $W$ is characterized by the fact that $\mathbb{P}(X\in B)=\frac{|B\cap W|}{|W|}$, where $B$ is a measurable set and $|X|$ is the Lebesgue measure of a measurable set $X$.

If we denote by $Y$ the restriction of $X$ to a disc $\mathcal{D}$ included in $W$, then for a measurable set $B$,

$$\mathbb{P}(Y\in B)=\mathbb{P}(X\in B\,|\,X\in\mathcal{D})=\frac{\mathbb{P}(X\in B\cap\mathcal{D})}{\mathbb{P}(X\in\mathcal{D})}=\frac{|B\cap\mathcal{D}|}{|\mathcal{D}|},$$

hence $Y$ is uniformly distributed on the disc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is this the only way to proof that?